# Client Certificate with Safari View Controller

Tags: xcode, mobile-safari

I have an application that is authenticated in a Safari View Controller using a client certificate. Unfortunately, when I redirect the SVC to the authentication page, I get an error saying:

```
"xxx" requires a client certificate
Use the certificate "xxx" when connecting to this website.
```

The device has the certificate, this certificate is trusted, and I am using the latest version of iOS.

Thanks in advance!